# How exactly does eval work with nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I do:

```
eval(
 db_config = {
                        host: 'localhost',
                        user: 'root',
                        database: 'forum',
                        password: 'test'
                    }
);

 var gamefunctions = require('gamefunctions.js');
```

I can use `db_config` anywhere inside `gamefunctions.js` without having to pass it through a parameter. That's pretty neat. But, is this bad practice?

Reason I ask this is because if I do:

```
 var db_config = {
                        host: 'localhost',
                        user: 'root',
                        database: 'forum',
                        password: 'test'
                    }


 var gamefunctions = require('gamefunctions.js');
```

`db_config` becomes undefined anytime I use it in `gamefunctions.js`. And I would have to pass it through a parameter on each different function which just seems like `evaling` it first would save time and code, any downside to this?

Does `eval` basically just define the variables in a global scope for you, so they can be used in any file in nodejs?

Comment: Yes; that is _atrociously_ bad practice.

Comment: Regardless of `eval`, defining a variable without `var` will make it global. And this _is_ bad practice.

Comment: What I'm confused about is: If I don't define db_config, I have to pass it through every single function I create. Which is tiresome and seems unintuitive, when I could just eval it, I can use the db_config object/variable freely wherever I want... which is so much nicer. Unless there is some type of security issue with doing this.. I don't think I'll change.. lol

Comment: Variables in Node are isolated to the module or file they're declared within. Generally speaking, true globals are a bit of an anti-pattern in Node (note: [skipping the `var` is how it becomes a global](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it), not the `eval()`). If you need a variable in multiple modules, you should attach it to the `module.exports` of one module and `require()` that in the others.

Comment: Oh wow @JonathanLonowski did not know that without var it became global inside node. Thank you for that. Yeah, I will not need to use eval now.  Edit: Yep, now db_config working inside gamefunctions w/o var added thanks much!

Comment: `eval()` takes a string so the first block code you show would not even work.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing 2 things wrong and there's much more elegant solution to this.

To explain what you're doing wrong, first is the use of globals. Second is that you're storing sensitive information in your code - your database password! And besides, it won't be very portable. Suppose you want to run it on another machine that has some other database credentials you'll end up changing your code unnecessarily.

You need to store it as environment variables. And if you end up hosting it some environments automatically have those set for you so you could use them in your app. For example openshift would have an `$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST` that it tells you to use in your app to connect to its database.

And you need to create a separate file to store your `db_config` which you can require from other files.

So you might create a `db_config.js` which would look like this

```
var config = {};
config.host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
config.user = process.env.USER || 'root';
config.password = process.env.password;
module.exports = config;
```

Then you can safely just pass it the sensitive information like password from console

```
$ password=pass
$ node index.js
```

And as for having that information in your `gamefunctions.js` all you gotta do is require it

```
var db_config = require('./db_config');
```

Comment: So, you think storing a database password in your environment is a safe practice where any script or program can access it?  Flexible yes, but safe?

Comment: @jfriend00 I think I should've said it's saf*er* than storing it in your code. But yes, I thought that's the best place to store your database passwords.

Comment: OK, I'd disagree.  I think the config file approach the OP was using is exactly what config files are for and better than environment variables.  You simply modify the config file when you deploy in a different environment.  That's what config files are for.  It also makes the various configurable settings for the app entirely documented and self describing.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm concerned that if you host that code up on github you have your password out in the open. I've read that there are bots scanning public repos for exactly such sensitive info.

Comment: Yeah.  I guess I thought it was kind of a "duh" that you don't put your DB password on a publicly accessible github.  Your scheme requires creating some script that sets environment variables which is something else you'd have to avoid putting on github.